# NodeJS and MySQL: getting array data inside query callback

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to run this piece of code:

```
setInterval(function () {

    var params = {
        QueueUrl: 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/821808622769/Teste', // required
        MaxNumberOfMessages: 10
    };
    sqs.receiveMessage(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err)
            console.log('Erro de SQS:' + err);
        else {
            var retorno = data.Messages;
            for (var i in data.Messages) {

                var queryString = 'SELECT now()'; //dummy query, just for tests
                db_connection.query(queryString, null, function (err, rows, fields) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('Erro no BD:' + err);
                        return;
                    }

                    var date = new Date();
                    console.log(retorno[i].Body + ' ' + date.getTime().toString());
                });

            }
            console.log();
        }
    });
}, 30000);
```

and I have 5 messages in AWS SQS, such as this:

[image: AWS table data]

but when I run my code, instead of having the retorno[i].Body of each message, sometimes I get a message repeated, as show in this image

[image: Console output]

My for loop is running from 1 to 5 queries, but how do I carry the retorno[i] inside the callback to the database query? I mean, how do I identify which message I was dealing with?

Answer (score 0):

Using .bind() you can setting the internal version of `i` to be the same as the version of `i` in your loop.

`.bind({i:i})` at the end of your callback and change the internal code to reference `this.i`

```
for (var i in data.Messages) {

  var queryString = 'SELECT now()'; //dummy query, just for tests
  db_connection.query(queryString, null, function(err, rows, fields) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Erro no BD:' + err);
        return;
      }

      var date = new Date();
      console.log(retorno[this.i].Body + ' ' + date.getTime().toString());
    }.bind({
      i: i
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll test this as soon as possible. This bind comes from node-mysql library? Can you post a link from documentation where I can read more about it?

Comment: The bind function is part of the ECMAScript (JavaScript) spec. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind